# Linked scene in VSE doesn't run Python script

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, linked-data, scene

I'm making a short movie in which one scene, I hide part of the mesh of a character using some python code in a Register .py file, like this:

```
bpy.data.objects['spider_eye.L'].modifiers['Mask.001'].show_viewport = 1
```

which hides the mesh in the animation file (*anim.blend*). I also have another blend file (*vse.blend*) where I linked the scene from the *anim.blend* to edit it but in the sequencer viewer of the VSE, the mesh is not hidden.

[image: Screenshot of vse.blend and anim.blend]

I'm guessing that when a scene is linked, the added code is not executed.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it would depend on how the script does it's thing. A registered script is run when opening the blend, is it just a script of simple commands like shown or is it doing things within a handler or driver? You could link the script as well as your mesh.

Comment: mod.show_viewport property shows / hides the result of modifier in the 3D Area's view, whereas I think you need to use  mod.show_render to hide result from the VSE

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, in the User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) you have **Auto Run Python Scripts** selected in the **File** Tab at the very bottom.

[image: File User Preferences]

Comment: I already had that option enable. I just want to know how the "Register" option in the text editor works.

Comment: Then you might ask a bit more specifically.